# Force base address for an executable compiled with -fPIE

Tags: c, linux, linker, aslr

I'm here with a somewhat strange question.

Is there a way to `exec` a program and specify the VirtualAddress that it should be loaded at?

Example:

`a.out` is a PIE, with entry point `0x460`.

`b.out` `fork` & `exec`'s `a.out`, but tells it, "Hey, I want to you load the `.text` section at `0x200000`, so the entry point is `0x200460`".

I looked at the POSIX `exec` function family, `ld.so`, and `ld-linux.so.2`, but didn't see anything that would let be do this.

My immediate solution is to write my own linker, but if there's something that will let me do this already, that would make my life a lot easier.

Thanks!

Comment: You could write your own loader: mmap the image, populate the PLT, and call the entry point.

Comment: Yeahhhhh, that's what I was thinking. Just hoping there was an avenue that I wasn't aware of.